# How to get updated DOM element javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying the fetch dynamic DOM elements from javascript and as per the current development, I can successfully fetch the updated DOM HTMLCollection array object. But when I try to print the innerHTML it gives previous DOM value. Below the console output which I am facing right now:

Console output for HTMLcollection: Highlighted part, that I want to fetch:
[image]

But when I try to get innerHTML for that element, I am getting the previous innerHTML instead I want to print current DOM innerHTML. Below is the screenshot of the output:

[image]

as we can see both screenshots of the same DOM element, gives different output. and this is javascript code I am trying fetch innerHTML:

```
var $wrap = document.getElementsByClassName('single_variation_wrap')[0];
    var $deposit_amount = document.getElementById('deposit-amount');
    var $display_amount = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-variation single_variation');
    $display_amount = $display_amount[0];
    var $final_display_amount = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-variation-price');
    console.log($deposit_amount, $final_display_amount);
    for(var i=0; i<$final_display_amount[0].childNodes.length;i++){
      console.log($final_display_amount[0].childNodes[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Please suggest, where am I doing things wrong?

Comment: You select all your nodes as `document.getElementsByClassName()`. If you have multiple `$wrap`s, then `var $final_display_amount = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-variation-price');` will refer to the first price, not the price associated with the selected `$wrap`. So I have a hunch that you have multiple items for sale and that you'll need to select the price node starting from the wrap: `var $final_display_amount = $wrap.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-variation-price');` so that you are sure to show the price for the selected product, not the first price on the page.

Comment: Your syntax is not correct, why are you using $ ?  This character is only required for JQuery references.

Comment: @SPlatten this is javascript script naming conversion, I can use $ in variables name. Please follow the link to know more: https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/javascript/naming-javascript-variables/

Comment: @Shilly, Yes I actually select all the prices which contain "woocommerce-variation-price" class element but I can only get one element array list. As you can see I am actually getting the correct value on 1st screenshot but when I try to get innerHTML of that element, i am getting incorrect html value.

Comment: @Sahadev, when used with JQuery it adds something to the variable, without JQuery, unless something else adds functionality to the variable it is NOT required and gives you nothing.

Comment: @SPlatten, Yes I can understand your concern but I am not using $ sign directly, I have given variable names with $ sign so it will not affect on my variables from jQuery library, but as per the your guidance i have checked with that also. still has same error.

Comment: @Sahadev, can you edit your post and include the HTML, I cannot access the links due to company firewall.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203157/discussion-between-sahadev-and-splatten).

Comment: @Sahadev, hopefully with a more robust approach to the coding implementation you will find a solution, good luck!

Comment: Yes, Maybe  I can found another better approach. Thanks @SPlatten

Comment: On topic: Being able to see the full HTML will make it easier to see why exactly the wrong innerHTML is shown. Sidenote: it used to be common to prefix all variables that selects elements, like with `$( 'someSelector' )` in JQuery, with a $ as well to signify they are JQuery elements. Hence after moving away from jquery, some people like to still prefix their DOM selectors with $ as well, as a memo that the variable contains a DOM node. Compare with how in other coding styles all variables are preceeded with their type, like `const sName = 'john';` or `const iAge = 25;`.